# show image contrast in grayscale in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, grayscale, contrast

I'm trying to turn a normal picture to a grayscale image using a contrast function using a gray function that is defined by 2 double variables: x1, x1. (using GUI)

this is my main function:

```
function varargout = EX1b(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
               'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
               'gui_OpeningFcn', @EX1b_OpeningFcn, ...
               'gui_OutputFcn',  @EX1b_OutputFcn, ...
               'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
               'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end


function EX1b_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;

guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = EX1b_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = handles.output;



function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'),    get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function edit2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function edit2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function edit3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function edit3_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end

function SUBMIT_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[filename path]=uigetfile('*.*', 'Select a file')
if(filename==0)
    return
end

[img, map]= imread(fullfile(path, filename));

axes(handles.axes3) %control axes 3 (==input picture)
image(img)
axes(handles.axes7) %control axes7  (==graph)
try
x1Text = get(handles.edit2, 'string');
x2Text = get(handles.edit3, 'string');

x1Val=str2double(x1Text);
x2Val=str2double(x2Text);

grayInput = linspace(0,1);
grayOutput= setAline(grayInput, x1Val, x2Val);
plot(grayInput, grayOutput);
catch
    return
end

axes(handles.axes4)  %control axes 4 (==output picture)

handles.a = imread(fullfile(path, filename));
image (handles.a)
im2 = imContrast(handles.a, x1Val, x2Val);


image(im2)
axis off
```

this is the 2 functions I'm using:

```
function im2 = imContrast(im1, x1, x2)

d = 1 / (x2-x1);       %distance between x1 and x2.
%display interface
im2(find(im1<=x1))=0;  %range before x1 (include x1).

im2(find(im1>=x2))=1;  %range after x2 (include x2).

im2(find(im1>x1 & im1 < x2)) = d * (im1(im1>x1 & im1<x2)-x1); %range from x1 to x2 (exclude x1, x2).

end
```

and

```
function grayOutput = setAline( grayInput, x1, x2 )

line = 1 / (x2-x1);                 %range from x1 to x2 (exclude x1, x2)

grayOutput(find(grayInput<=x1))=0;  %range before x1 (include x1)

grayOutput(find(grayInput>=x2))=1;  %range after x2 (include x2)

grayOutput(find(grayInput>x1 & grayInput < x2)) = line * (grayInput(grayInput>x1 & grayInput<x2)-x1);

end
```

when running the program, enter into GUI in x1, x2 2 numbers between 0 to 1 (0.2 and 0.5), press SUBMIT and choose any picture.
Instead of a grayscale image, I'm getting a completely blue image.
(as added)[image]

hope it was clear...
thanks you very much

Comment: Can you post an image and a [mcve] which we can run?

Comment: I'm not sure how.. I'm working with GUI, so there's a lot of unneseccary code. I tried adding only the relevant code.
and I used just any picture, it doesn't matter

Comment: Just try creating the simplest GUI that reproduces the error and upload the code.

Comment: I tried.. please tell me if this is what you meant. thank you very much

Comment: I still get an error when running this. If you can't upload anything that runs, you could have a look what your image data looks like, just before it gets displayed (I guess that's the line image(im2)). You can do this by using the debug modus and setting a breakpoint at this line. What does the data look like?

Comment: thank you, I found the problem